# Basic question on p-adic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I have a very basic question about $p$-adic numbers that arose while reading about $p$-divisible group-schemes. On the very first page of [this paper](http://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/pDivGroups.pdf) for instance, as well as in other sources, it is suggested that

$$\lim_{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$$

which surprizes me because as far as I know, this inductive limit actually is the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (as I see it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Algebraic_approach)).

Could someone please confirm whether the above isomorphism is true (ie. exists), and if yes, explain why we have this identity?

I thank you very much.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) is what  you're looking for.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much @ÍgjøgnumMeg !

Comment: By the way, the isomorphism you mention here is obtained by mapping $a \mod{p^n}$ to $a/p^n$.

Comment: And here’s a pleasant exercise for you: to show that $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Z_p)\cong\Bbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductive limit is indeed what you said. First you need to say how do you send $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}$. This is with a map **as abelian groups** (not as a rings) given by sending $1$ to $p$. So we identify $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ with the subgroup $p\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}$.

Now the inductive limit becomes the union when you put everything inside the correct place: $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$. This is done by sending $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ to the subgroup $\frac 1{p^n}\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ form by the elements killed for multiplication by ${p^n}$, sending $1$ to the class of this $p$-adic number $\frac 1{p^n}$. Clearly this subgroup has order $p^n$, so the map is an isomorphism. Finally, any element of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ has order $p^n$ for some $n\ge 0$, so 
$$\mathbb{Q_p}/\mathbb{Z_p}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \frac 1{p^n}\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p\cong\lim_{\to} \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this very clear answer, @xarles .

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the direct (inductive) limit, but the definition of $\mathbf Z_p$ is that it is the *inverse* or *projective* limit:
$$\mathbf Z_p=\varprojlim \mathbf Z/p^n \mathbf Z=\Bigl\{(\bar x_n)\in\prod_n\mathbf Z/p^n \mathbf Z\mid x_{n+1}\equiv x_n\bmod p^n \Bigr\}$$

Comment: You are right, thank you very much for pointing this out.